# bundle install not installing gem of production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I run `bundle install` it is not installing gem of production group.

Some day ago I have run `bundle install --without production`. But Now I want to install gem of production also. How can I install gem with production also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe once you run the bundler using `--without production` it remembers that setting in the config. So you should be able to undo it by changing the config per the [bundle config](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_config.html) command.